# How can iplocation.net know my country if I use a VPN thru Opera Mini on Android?

Tags: vpn, android, ip, geolocation

How can iplocation.net know my country if I use a VPN thru Opera Mini on Android?

Accessing myip.com it says "no country".

But accessing iplocation.net shows my real city and provider! And a different IP address from myip.com, of course.

What's the point of Opera mini VPN at all?

Comment: How do you know you have actually enabled VPN in Opera Mini? How do you know this feature exists and working? And they you need to explicitly trust Opera to have a working VPN implementation.

Comment: What IP adresses (IPv4 and IPv6) does iplocation.net show? What IP addresses does myip.com show? If these are the same then they have a different mapping from IP to location (there are different databases for this, none 100% correct). What IP claims Opera mini VPN to use compared to this?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Because i cant tyrn it off (cant find option for it), and at myip.com it cant detect the country, and at iplocation.net the ip is from netherlands, but all that is already in my question detailed body text.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the ip i get at myip.com differs from the one i get at iplocation.net. i think i should not typing the ips here right? What i can say is that they differ, and u can confirm by performing the described tests.

Comment: Please review the various related questions on the side. There are many ways for a site to know your actual location even if you use a VPN. Please note that VPNs are primarily a tool to deal with security between you and the target site. VPNs can be used to provide some level of anonymity to the target site, but they are not designed for that and effectiveness varies.

Comment: @VeganEye: Opera mini provides the original IP address in a `X-Forwarded-For` header and this is what iplocation.net is using as base of the location. See https://tools.iplocation.net/http-browser-header. I would not expect this behavior from their claim of *"Browse with a virtual IP address that helps hide your location"* - but it is clearly there. And note that what their are using as not an actual VPN (i.e. network level), it is a proxy (application level). And they have also access to your encrypted (HTTPS) traffic.

Comment: @schroeder i will review them as soon i can, btw, my goal is to make a anonymous complaint, but i know it wont be anonymous the moment they get my real ip. I thought VPNs would help on that, any tip about it? Should i create such new specific question?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i think that probably answers my question thx! Btw, i guess they can also easily decrypt my https traffic based on this https://superuser.com/questions/1809307/is-https-really-secure-about-the-first-data-packet-transmitted

Comment: @VeganEye: Given that they can include the X-Forwarded-For header into a HTTPS connection it means that they have access to the decrypted content and can modify it. But of course, since one is using the browser from them they can have access to this content anyway, even before HTTPS.